# One time password OTP docker container throwing redis error

Tags: docker, redis, dockerfile, devops, one-time-password

Trying to setup docker container for OTP using this github repository

[git hub repo for One time secret OTP link](https://github.com/dismantl/onetimesecret-docker)

Running the container though the build is success,I get the following error on docker logs.

```
Generating OTS secret: a0bfb6124d95339d62ddb847eabf26e0a46828a4
Generating Redis password: e2ee2e4e2ba560ee9e95d32d947c74f33a259e02
/var/lib/onetime/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:47:in `call': ERR Client sent AUTH, but no password is set (RuntimeError)
    from /var/lib/onetime/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:24:in `connect'
    from /var/lib/onetime/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:247:in `ensure_connected'
    from /var/lib/onetime/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:137:in `block in process'
    from /var/lib/onetime/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:206:in `logging'
    from /var/lib/onetime/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:136:in `process'
    from /var/lib/onetime/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:46:in `call'
    from /var/lib/onetime/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis.rb:273:in `block in ping'
    from /var/lib/onetime/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis.rb:18:in `synchronize'
    from /var/lib/onetime/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis.rb:272:in `ping'
    from /var/lib/onetime/lib/onetime.rb:73:in `block in load!'
    from /var/lib/onetime/lib/onetime.rb:73:in `times'
    from /var/lib/onetime/lib/onetime.rb:73:in `load!'
    from config.ru:28:in `block in <main>'
    from /var/lib/onetime/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /var/lib/onetime/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from config.ru:1:in `new'
    from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /var/lib/onetime/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
    from /var/lib/onetime/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
    from /var/lib/onetime/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
    from /var/lib/onetime/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
    from /var/lib/onetime/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
    from /var/lib/onetime/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
    from /var/lib/onetime/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/thin-1.5.0/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/onetime/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/thin:22:in `load'
    from /var/lib/onetime/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/thin:22:in `<main>'
```

What exactly is the problem. Where do I exactly set that password.

Comment: How are you launching the app? The error comes from the redis client, which redis container are you connecting to?

Comment: @jaxxstorm I am just  building the image from the Dockerfile in the repo and running it. Even the docker-compose doesnot have the redis service included . Do I have to add that service too or how can i solve it

Comment: It seems to be included in the entrypoint: https://github.com/dismantl/onetimesecret-docker/blob/master/entrypoint.sh#L36 it will need forking to fix

Comment: what fix can you suggest the exact  fix @jaxxstorm